# Java Example: Enter Key. Java Novice

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Thank you for taking the time to read this but I'll make it simple. The problem I have is that I have a program that changes one type of temperature and converts it to another. The thing I want to add to the program is that when the person clicks the button enter it shows the the new temperature in another box when the person clicks "enter" on their keyboard. This is the code below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;


public class Testlab {

    static String celciusString = "Celcius";
    static String fahrenheitString = "Fahrenheit";
    static String kelvinString = "Kelvin";

    static String celcius1String = "Celcius2";
    static String fahrenheit1String = "Fahrenheit2";
    static String kelvin1String = "Kelvin2";

    private JLabel in = new JLabel("Input Scale");
    private JLabel out = new JLabel("Output Scale");

    private JLabel in1 = new JLabel("Input");
    private JLabel out1 = new JLabel("Output");

    private JTextField input = new JTextField(7);
    private JTextField output = new JTextField(7);

    private JFrame f = new JFrame("BasicGui"); // Create Frame
    private JPanel pnlNorth = new JPanel(); //North Quadrant
    private JPanel pnlSouth = new JPanel(); //South Quadrant
    private JPanel pnlEast = new JPanel(); //East Quadrant
    private JPanel pnlWest = new JPanel(); // West Quadrant
    private JPanel pnlCenter = new JPanel(); // Center Quadrant


    private JRadioButton celciusButton = new JRadioButton(celciusString);
    private JRadioButton fahrenheitButton = new JRadioButton(fahrenheitString);
    private JRadioButton kelvinButton = new JRadioButton(kelvinString);

    private JRadioButton celcius1Button = new JRadioButton(celciusString);
    private JRadioButton fahrenheit1Button = new JRadioButton(fahrenheitString);
    private JRadioButton kelvin1Button = new JRadioButton(kelvinString);

    //Menu
    private JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar(); // Menu Bar
    private JMenu mnuFile = new JMenu("File"); // File Entry of Menu Bar
    private JMenuItem mnuItemQuit = new JMenuItem("Quit"); // Quit Sub item
    private JMenu mnuHelp = new JMenu("Help"); //Help Menu Entry
    private JMenuItem mnuItemAbout = new JMenuItem("About"); //About Entry

    //Constructor for GUI
    public Testlab(){
        //Set Menubar
        pnlEast.setLayout(new GridLayout (4,1));
        pnlWest.setLayout(new GridLayout (4,1));

        f.setJMenuBar(mb);

        //Radio Button --New
        celciusButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        celciusButton.setActionCommand(celciusString);
        celciusButton.setSelected(true);

        fahrenheitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        fahrenheitButton.setActionCommand(fahrenheitString);

        kelvinButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_K);
        kelvinButton.setActionCommand(kelvinString);

        celcius1Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        celcius1Button.setActionCommand(celcius1String);
        celcius1Button.setSelected(true);

        fahrenheit1Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        fahrenheit1Button.setActionCommand(fahrenheit1String);

        kelvin1Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_K);
        kelvin1Button.setActionCommand(kelvin1String);

        //Group the radio Buttons.

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(celciusButton);
        group.add(fahrenheitButton);
        group.add(kelvinButton);

        ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
        group2.add(celcius1Button);
        group2.add(fahrenheit1Button);
        group2.add(kelvin1Button);


        //Register A listener for the radio Buttons.
        celciusButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonEvent());
        fahrenheitButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonEvent());
        kelvinButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonEvent());

        celcius1Button.addActionListener(new RadioButtonEvent());
        fahrenheit1Button.addActionListener(new RadioButtonEvent());
        kelvin1Button.addActionListener(new RadioButtonEvent());


        //Build Menus
        mnuFile.add(mnuItemQuit); //Create Quit Line
        mnuHelp.add(mnuItemAbout); //Create About Line
        mb.add(mnuFile);        // Add Menu Items to form
        mb.add(mnuHelp);

        //Add Buttons
        //pnlNorth.add(btnNorth);

        pnlNorth.add(in1);
        pnlSouth.add(out1);
        pnlNorth.add(input);
        pnlSouth.add(output);

        pnlWest.add(in);
        pnlWest.add(celciusButton);
        pnlWest.add(fahrenheitButton);
        pnlWest.add(kelvinButton);

        pnlEast.add(out);
        pnlEast.add(celcius1Button);
        pnlEast.add(fahrenheit1Button);
        pnlEast.add(kelvin1Button);


        //Setup Main Frame
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(pnlSouth,BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        f.getContentPane().add(pnlEast,BorderLayout.EAST );
        f.getContentPane().add(pnlWest,BorderLayout.WEST );
        f.getContentPane().add(pnlCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Allows the Swing App to be closed
        f.addWindowListener(new ListenCloseWdw());

        // Add Menu Listener
        mnuItemQuit.addActionListener(new ListenMenuQuit());
    }

    public class ListenMenuQuit implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }   

    }



    //NEW STUFF TO ADD
    public class RadioButtonEvent implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String action = e.getActionCommand();

            int temperture;
            double newtemperture = 0.00;
            try {
            temperture = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());

        if (celciusButton.isSelected() & celcius1Button.isSelected())

             newtemperture = temperture;


        else if (celciusButton.isSelected() & fahrenheit1Button.isSelected())

            newtemperture = ((temperture * 1.8)) + 32;

            else if (celciusButton.isSelected() & kelvin1Button.isSelected())

                newtemperture = temperture + 273.15;

            else if (fahrenheitButton.isSelected() & celcius1Button.isSelected())

                newtemperture = (temperture - 32) * .55555555555;

            else if (fahrenheitButton.isSelected() & fahrenheit1Button.isSelected())

                newtemperture = temperture;

            else if (fahrenheitButton.isSelected() & kelvin1Button.isSelected())

                newtemperture = (temperture + 459.67) * 5/9;

            else if (kelvinButton.isSelected() & celcius1Button.isSelected())

                newtemperture = (temperture - 273.15);

            else if (kelvinButton.isSelected() & fahrenheit1Button.isSelected())

                newtemperture = (temperture * 9/5) - 459.67;

            else if (kelvinButton.isSelected() & kelvin1Button.isSelected())

                newtemperture = temperture;


            } catch (Exception a) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not input a value");
            }



         output.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(newtemperture));
            }
    }



    public class ListenCloseWdw extends WindowAdapter{
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }

    public void launchFrame(){
        //Display Frame
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack(); // Adjusting panel to components for Display
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Testlab gui = new Testlab();
        gui.launchFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest reading up on Oracle's Java Swing tutorial: [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). Also, for future reference, please try to include only the necessary code in your post rather than the whole class.

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look and thank you for the suggestion. I'll try to that next time I post a problem.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas : No never encourage use of `KeyListener`, in Swing, always consider [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), for that matter. `KeyListener` is way too low level for `Swing`

Comment: The normally used "and" is `&&` which is a short-cut operator, not necessarily evaluating the RHS: `s != null && s.equals(t)` will yield `false` when `s` is null.

Comment: See also [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Comment: @nIcEcOw - The third line in the linked tutorial says "To define special reactions to particular keys, use key bindings instead of a key listener." That particular tutorial is, however, a good general introduction. But I suppose [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) on keybindings would have been a better link to provide.

Answer (score 3):

Just add to `Testlab()`:

```
input.addActionListener(new RadioButtonEvent());
```

Also don't create identical ActionListeners for every component. You can create only one and register it to any number of components.